# Next.js SSR also render page props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Im trying to do SSR to my React + Next.js application. I have a proble with rendering dynamic modules. In `_app.js` I'm loading data and put them to my redux-saga. This is working fine but my SSR does not works for that data, because Im trying to render component with redux data instead of component props.

SSR only works, when I do api call inside getInitialProps, and put those requests via getInitialProps to my component. This is weird behaviour for me but let it be. It works by this but now I got another problem.

All those data that is responsible for my content are also listed in page view source. WTF - why there are in html content. Also because of that my page source view is loading few minutes.

Is there any option to not put those props into page source view ?